# Can't require ruby gems on windows 10

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed *ruby -v 2.2.4 (64x)* on *Windows 10* from it's [official website](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). The setup completed successfully, but ruby isn't able to require gems. Whenever I run the following command from IRB:

```
require 'minitest'
```

It fails with the output:

> LoadError: cannot load such file --
>           from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   'require'
>           from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   'require'
>           from (irb):1
>           from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in '< main>'

---

### Gem list:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

---

### RubyGems Environment:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.4 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 230) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby22/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/alexl/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - C:/Users/alexl/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\Users\alexl\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Users\alexl\bin
     - C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
     - C:\Windows\system32
     - C:\Windows
     - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone
     - C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\Todo Backup\bin
     - C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15
     - C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
     - C:\Ruby22\bin
     - C:\Users\alexl\AppData\Local\atom\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
```

I have googled around for some time, but could not find any useful information about resolving this issue.

---

### Edit 1

I have uninstalled the *x64* version and installed the *x86* one. The error still persists

Comment: FWIW: from the sidebar on  http://rubyinstaller.org/download - "The 64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too complicated if you just want to play with the language."

Comment: Is `minitest` even installed?

Comment: Yes, minitest is installed. The gem comes bundled with ruby, so it shouldn't have compatibility issues on x64

Comment: @AlexanderLomia: Please post the output of `gem list`. I'm pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia: [`minitest` was removed from the stdlib in 2.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_4/NEWS#L238-L243). 5.4.3 is also neither a current version (2014?) nor was it ever bundled. But `require` isn't failing just with `minitest`, is it? Can you also post the output of `gem environment`? Maybe a previous installation wasn't correctly removed or sth.

Comment: @cremno I added the output into the question